# Create Core in Cloudera

Tags: java, solr, cloudera

I want to index DATA but it seems not easy in cloudera VM.Because the API of Solr demands to create a Core.so I Want to create a core which usual name is collection1 . I am Using cloudera-quickstart-vm-4.7.0-0-vmware in which it is absolutely we need to create Core.
So how can I process.
any help from those with more knowledge would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To create a new collection in Cloudera Search you can follow these steps:

Create a folder to use as the destination for the Solr configuration files, such as `mkdir myNewCollection`
Run the following command to get a copy of the default configuration files for a Solr collection:

```
solrctl --zk localhost:2181/solr instancedir --generate /myNewCollection
```

Create an instance folder in the Solr nodes for the the collection to be created:

```
solrctl --zk yourhost:2181/solr instancedir --create myNewCollection /myNewCollection
```

Create the collection:

```
solrctl --zk yourhost:2181/solr collection --create myNewCollection
```